# Naming: WorkspaceViewModelFactory or WorkspaceVMFactory or WorkspaceViewModel_Factory?

Tags: c#, .net, naming-conventions, coding-style, naming

According to naming conventions, which one is recommenced?

```
* WorkspaceViewModelFactory
* WorkspaceVMFactory
* WorkspaceViewModel_Factory
* WorkspaceVM_Factory
* Workspace_ViewModel_Factory
* Workspace_VM_Factory
```

In case that matters: I'm a hobbyist programmer, I'm the only one who has to read my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one `WorkspaceViewModelFactory`.

Quote #1 from [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)

> When an identifier consists of
>   multiple words, do not use separators,
>   such as underscores ("_") or hyphens
>   ("-"), between words. Instead, use
>   casing to indicate the beginning of
>   each word.

This rules out all the options that have `_`.

Quote #2 from [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx)

> In general, you should not use
>   abbreviations or acronyms. These make
>   your names less readable. Similarly,
>   it is difficult to know when it is
>   safe to assume that an acronym is
>   widely recognized.

This rules out all the options that have `VM` in the name and leaves just one clear option `WorkspaceViewModelFactory`.